# Qt: QFormLayout - How to find the row from the button

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

How to find the row number of `QFormLayout()` from a button which is in that row? I have a delete button on each row of the form. Such that if I click the delete button, that specific row will get deleted. For this, I am planning to use the command `QtWidgets.QFormLayout.removeRow(row)` command. I have defined the `QFormLayout()` within my `def __init__(self):` function like so.

```
self.attachForm = QFormLayout()
```

I also have an `Add` button which calls the `self.attachBtn_clicked(self)` function given below. So every time the `Add` button is clicked a new row is added. Any help will be appreciated.

```
def attachBtn_clicked(self):
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    self.attachForm.addRow('',hbox)

    browseBtn = QPushButton("Open")
    hbox.addWidget(browseBtn)

    addAttachEdit = QLineEdit()
    hbox.addWidget(addAttachEdit)

    delAttachBtn = QPushButton("x")
    delAttachBtn.setFixedSize(15,15)
    delAttachBtn.clicked.connect(self.delAttachBtn_clicked)
    hbox.addWidget(delAttachBtn)
```

The objective is now to write the `self.delAttachBtn_clicked(self)` function which will delete the specific row.

Comment: why are you not using tableView ?
with tableView you can easily get row, columns and values.

Comment: Since it is a form requiring input from the user, for which QFormLayout is generally used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the rows and find the button that matches the sender.

```
def delAttachBtn_clicked(self):
    for i in range(self.attachForm.rowCount()):
        if self.sender() == self.attachForm.itemAt(i, QFormLayout.FieldRole).itemAt(2).widget():
            self.attachForm.removeRow(i)
            return
```

`itemAt(2)` is used since `delAttachBtn` is the 3rd item in each QHBoxLayout.